# Are there scenarios where using package::function syntax in R might cause issues?

Tags: r

While running `library(package)` will load the exported functions/objects in a package's namespace into the global environment, I've come to prefer the more verbose but more explicit `package::function()` syntax for using those functions/objects, which not only avoids namespace conflicts but also makes it clear to subsequent code-readers where the functions/objects I'm using come from. Before I start recommending this practice to my colleagues/students, I thought I'd check if anyone happens to know of any scenarios where this unconventional usage might cause issues. Any thoughts?

Comment: Note: `library` doesn't load exported functions into the global environment, it adds a namespace to the search path.

Comment: It's totally conventional and highly recommended to use said idiom within packages, so you're just expanding said recommendation. It's also becoming increasingly necessary to do this, too (conflicts between dplyr, purr, scales, plyr and others).